# Symfony2 Best practices - sorting of entities

Tags: model-view-controller, sorting, symfony, architecture, doctrine

I am creating an application in Symfony2. This is the first time I develop using a framework and one of my first projects. It is a student project.

In this project, I want my collections of entities to be sorted somewhere before reaching the view. This can be done in this way:

In getters on the entities on the many-to-one relations, with comparator methods on the many-side that is used by the usort() method in the getter on the one-side. Below I have a method that also fills in gaps in a collection of "Day" entities (in a form of diary), but the point is that it sorts the days with usort.

In User entity class:

```
public function getDaysWithNulls()
    {
    $days = $this->getDays()->toArray();
    //get the first day and find out how many days have passed
    usort($days, array("\Pan100\MoodLogBundle\Entity\Day", "daySorter"));
    $firstEntry = $days[0];
    $interval = $firstEntry->getDate()->diff(new \DateTime());
    $numberOfDaysBack = $interval->d;
    //create an array consisting of the number of days back
    $daysToShow = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < $numberOfDaysBack ; $i++) { 
        $date = new \DateTime();
        $date->sub(new \DateInterval('P' . $i . 'D'));
        $daysToShow[] = $date;
    }
    $daysToReturn = array();
    foreach ($daysToShow as $day) {
        //figure out if this day has an entity, if not set an empty Day object
        $dayEntityToProcess = new \Pan100\MoodLogBundle\Entity\Day();
        $dayEntityToProcess->setDate($day);
        foreach ($days as $dayEntity) {
            //check if there is a day entity
            if($day->format('Y-m-d') == $dayEntity->getDate()->format('Y-m-d')) {
                $dayEntityToProcess = $dayEntity;
            } 
        }
        $daysToReturn[] = $dayEntityToProcess;
    }
    //return a collection
    return new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection($daysToReturn);
}
```

usort uses this in the Day entity class:

```
static function daySorter($dayEntity1, $dayEntity2) {
    $interval = $dayEntity1->getDate()->diff($dayEntity2->getDate());
    if($interval->invert == 1) {
        return +1;
    }
    else if ($interval->invert == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else return -1;
}
```

**My question is: is this the best practice for sorting and returning sorted collections, or should sorting happen somewhere else?**

Comment: a little remark: I read somewhere that one should not use the EntityManager in the entity classes to query, as it ties the layers. Otherwise I could have queried the EntityManager for the days sorted by day.

Answer (score 1):

I did think this was a tedoius way of doing it. So I searched the web a bit, and read some more, and found that I can create custom repositories.

I will do it this way instead:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

EDIT: found out the sorting is better done in annotations:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Day", mappedBy="user_id")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"date" = "DESC"})     
 **/    
protected $days;
```